# Calculate percentile value of raster

Tags: arcpy, python, raster, raster-calculator, calculate-values

I want to set null all raster values that fall below the 75th percentile value. E.g. If you classify the raster by quantile method into 4 classes I want to be left with the top 25% percentile. For the raster shown below, 3.154941635 would be used in the set null expression.

I have attempted the following in the Calculate Value tool and a value of 0 is being returned. (source:https://community.esri.com/thread/162022)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you attempting to use the Calculate Value tool within Model Builder? If so, please, specify exactly how you are doing it by providing a print of your model.

Comment: Your model is just returining the 75% percentile of your input raster (wathever it is). You should use this value as the input to (e.g.) [SetNull](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/set-null.htm) tool (I assume you have a Spatial Analyst license at this point).

Comment: I have multiple rasters where the 75% percentile value needs to be used as a cut off. I therefore need to build this part of the tool before I use this value in the set null tool and iterate the entire process.

The calculate value tool is returning 0....not the value I am expecting.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to calculate the 75% percentile of many rasters and for each set all the cells that are lower than this percentile to null, is that correct? If this is correct and you wanna stick to Model Builder rather than using Python scripts, you should do what I said and integrate the final model as an iterator submodel to another model (like explained [here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/modelbuilder/integrating-model-within-a-model.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_FC4FA1B8DC0D418098AD21B774804821)). Hope it helps.

Comment: Anyway, I think your main problem is that you have "attempted the following in the Calculate Value tool and a value of 0 is being returned.". What is your source raster?

Comment: Yes, you are correct with what I am trying to do. I don't see how the 75th percentile value would be calculated within the SetNull tool? This value will vary from raster to raster hence I cant just enter it manually.

Comment: I think you could use [inline model variable substitution](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/modelbuilder/examples-of-inline-model-variable-substitution.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_592A852ABCD842FBBD8D5D12442AD8C8). Not completely sure, but if you put in the SetNull expression param somthing like `VALUE > %output_value%` could probably work.

Answer (score 0):

For one raster, try to build your model builder like:

[image]

**SetNull settings**:

[image]

**Expression** for SetNull:

[image]

Beware that ([reference](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/modelbuilder/examples-of-inline-model-variable-substitution.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_592A852ABCD842FBBD8D5D12442AD8C8)):

> Clicking the Verify button for an SQL query with an inline variable
>   substitution in Query Builder, for tools such as Make Feature Layer,
>   Select, and Select Layer By Attribute, will give you an invalid SQL
>   query error, as the verification does not substitute the value of the
>   inline variable when evaluating an expression. When the tool runs, the
>   value of the inline variable is substituted in the expression and the
>   results are created based on the substituted values.

Finally, as I said, you should use this model as a submodule used as an iterator to another model to run it against all your rasters (https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/modelbuilder/integrating-model-within-a-model.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_FC4FA1B8DC0D418098AD21B774804821).

Comment: I have no issue with how to set a null value. My issue is calculating the 75% percentile value from the input raster data set.

Comment: You said your attempt to running the Calculate Value led to 0 as result. I tried your same expression to calculate the 75% percentile against two different rasters and the result is correct. What is your source raster? Can you give more detail on the input raster you're using?

Comment: yes of course, thank you for your help. Floating point, 32 Bit, some rasters have up to 10 decimal places. 1 band WSG 1984.

Comment: I bet the problem is that many decimal places. The tool is (lkely) rounding it so you always get 0. Have you tried changing the percentile value to see if the output is different than zero? If this is the problem, you could try multiplying the values of your raster by a certain amount (like times 1000000), and see if that brings you to a different result. You can do that using the Raster Calculator before everything in your model and give the multiplied raster to the Calculate Value tool as input. just a guess, might work...

Comment: Values of 0 are returned for percentiles up to the 85th. For the 86th percentile and above a value is returned. Negative values are returned for the 41st percentile and below. One test using the 90th percentile returns a value that's more likely to be the 35th. I have tried a range of raster data sets, integer and decimal. No success

Comment: It probably means that for percentile lower than 86th, the result is 0.-a lot of zeros before another number. One workaround is to multiply the values of your rasters by a certain amount to shift the digits (e.g. *10000, or whatever multiple of 10), using the Raster Calculator, do run your Calculate Value again for the same 75th percentile, see if it is different than 0, and, if so, at the very end multiply your raster by the same amount.

Comment: Yes, tried that. No change in returned value. No change in including 75.00 into the percentile variable either.

Comment: And could 0 (zero) be a reasonable result then? I mean, have you tried looking at the values of your raster? Looking at the attribute table of your raster should give you an idea of that. If you don't have an attribute table already, then use the [Calculate Statistics](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-statistics.htm) tool.

Comment: No, I have classified the data using a quantile distribution of 10 classes so I know exactly what values should be returned from 50, 60, 70 etc. I've also tested this on different datasets and the 85/86 threshold of either returning zero or a result is the same.

Comment: I'd use arcpy.Raster(rasterlayername)